# VBA Like Function

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Basically my code works in such a way that an Incoming email subject from Outlook is compared to a list column in Excel - supposedly those existing email. If the Incoming email is matched with any records then it Shows the value in Excel. However, I noticed that, if the data in Excel contains the hashtag (#) value, even if the incoming email is not the same as the one in Excel- the code marks it as matched.

```
If emlSubj Like "*" & strSubj & "*" Then
Debug.Print strSubj
```

Is there something wrong with the code or is it the limitation of the LIKE function?

Comment: with `Like`, "*" stands for every characters sequence, so that "#" will match

Comment: @Wilson please edit your post and add the rest of your code (relevant section)

Comment: `#` is a wildcard as well. http://analystcave.com/vba-like-operator/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [InStr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) function instead. It returns an integer specifying the start position of the first occurrence of one string within another.

```
If InStr(emlSubj , strSubj) > 0 Then
   Debug.Print strSubj
End If
```

Comment: So I tried using the code above but it was not able to match the 2 subjects that I was comparing. For example, EmlSubj is Holiday Booking and StrSubj (the one in Excel file) is Holiday Booking #445. The code was not able to match the two subjects.

Comment: If InStr("Holiday Booking #445", "Holiday Booking") > 0 Then
   Debug.Print "FOUND"
End If

Comment: You need to specify a string where you are trying to search for a substring first. Then you declare a search term.

Comment: Thanks @Eugene. I used this instead - InStr(emlSubj , strSubj), basically switching the strings and everything is working properly.